# how to install Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_2_en.run on ubuntu11.04?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-11.04

i cannot install qt on ubuntu. i tried the following

```
  chmod u+x Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_3_en.run
./Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_3_en.run
```

and also

```
mv Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_2_en.run ./Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_2_en.bin
sudo su
chmod x Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_2_en.bin
./Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_2_en.bin.
```

Comment: the file not converted to executable mode.so i cannot run that file.permission denied.same problem in fedora 15 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new linux versions permission changes in windows partitions.so you cannot execute some files in windows filesystem.I am not sure,i think the file only works with your filesystem.
You just copy the file to dwsktop and execute it.I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The first one you tried should have work unless Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_3_en.run is stored in a device that doesn't allow execute files no matter what the permissions are set.

Comment: it is in a ntfs formatted drive.I always run executable from that drive.Is there any permission problems in Gnome3 ? Because the file is more than 1gb.

Comment: It's a bit strange. Anyway, have you tried to run that file using the _dot or source operator_? You don't need, AFAIK, to give execution permissions to the file you can launch it this way:   . ./Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_3_en.run  or   source ./Qt_SDK_Lin32_offline_v1_1_3_en.run